# $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$, the exponential function, some question.

Tags: probability, exponentiation, exponential-function

I have a question involving with $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$, define as $\int_{-x}^{\infty}e^u \cdot u^{-1} \mathrm{d}u$.

My question is, when I have a expression say $\exp(x) \cdot \mathrm{Ei}(x)+1$. 
I want to optimize this function in terms of $x$. Now, the question is how do I suppose to with this $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$ function?

Comment: The definition of the function is currently not right. You need $e^{-u}$.

Comment: Specifically: $\operatorname{Ei}(x) = {-}\int\limits_{-x}^\infty \frac{e^{-u}}{u}\;\mathrm{d}u$

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you "want to optimize this function in terms of $x$" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be helpful to note that 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int^{\infty}_{t}f(u)du=-f(t)$$